# JQuery set focus on uniform select

Tags: jquery, focus, jquery-uniform

A simple enough problem, probably with a stupidly simple solution, but I've been unable to find it anywhere.

How do you manually set focus on a select that has been processed by Uniform.js?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correct, i think you call jQuery focus() on the input as you normally would and then call `$.uniform.update();` to force uniform to update based on the change.

Comment: I've tried this several times, and it doesn't seem to work. Getting a handle on the select element itself using $('#select_id').focus(), then calling update on uniform, doesn't work. Any other suggestions?